# Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, bdd

I am getting this error while running my feature file don't know what's wrong sharing the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to import in the `.js` file? Could you provide the file ?

Comment: it's given above greenCartStepDef.js please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you had an old version of the package `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Because right now, the import is:

```
import {
  DataTable,
  Given,
  Then,
  When,
} from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
```

Comment: now it is giving the error for 'And' notation - ReferenceError
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.



  > And is not defined

Comment: If I remember well, `And` has been removed. So you can try to replace all the `And` by `Given` for example

Comment: @NeelChavan, with cypress-cucumber V13, you have this change `Remove And and But from the public API, fixes #821.` https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/releases/tag/v13.0.0

Comment: solved the issue thank you very much